# flutterfire_ui authentication unknown error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I receive `An error occurred while calling method Auth#signInWithCredential, errorOrNil => (null)`
with implementation of flutterfire_ui (0.3.1) on iOS.
Does anyone know what the reason for that?

[image]

No issue on Android tho

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there was an issue with App ID - different in the Flutter project, different on the Firebase. Generating new firebase_options fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me updating the SHA fingerprints of the corresponding app in Firebase solved the issue. I copied them from the Google Play Console as described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_play_app_signing).